# Is it possible to use Unity Addressable Assets from a Web Hosting Service?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cloud, web-hosting, assetbundle

I am currently developing a mobile game and I recently stumbled on Addressable Assets. I watched a few tutorials and I have placed my test assets onto my web server which I use with the web hosting service HostGator. The test prefabs that I have been using were instantiated while on my local machine, but have not appeared when I set them up on my web server. Is there a way to use addressable assets with a web hosting service, or am I stuck with AWS, Google Cloud, and other hosting services?

Comment: Did my answer help? If so could you Mark it as so? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've got the loading working from a custom webserver. So you should be able to do this without the use of any service.